# Facebook re-authentication in a popup window

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I write a windows forms application that connects to user's profile in facebook, reads his wall and shows him updates in a widget, with the help of facebook c# sdk.

Everything works fine, except for the fact that facebook won't let my user change his credentials, that means re-login as a different user.

My authentication flow is schematically as follows:

*In login process initializer:*

> note: The dialog is shown in a popup. If you show dialog in a full
>   browser, it's possible to logout, but in popup this functionality
>   seems to be lacking.

```
private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){     
    browser = new WebBrowser();
    this.browser.Navigated += new WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(browser_Navigated);
    //+ all types of gui settings for the borwser
    form.Controls.Add(browser);

    Uri url=new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + {*MyAppsId*}+
      "&redirect_uri=" + "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" +
      "&response_type=token"+
      "&auth_type=reauthenticate"+
      "&display=popup"+
      "&scope=read_stream"

    browser.Navigate(url);// +try/catches - omitted
}
```

*Navigation response parsing:*

note: just parsing the response with the use of c# sdk classes FacebookOAuthResult and FacebookClient

```
private void browser_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e){
    FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult; //helps to streamline parsing
    if (fb.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Url, out oauthResult)){ //type of fb is FacebookClient of c# sdk
        if (oauthResult.IsSuccess){
            accessToken = oauthResult.AccessToken;
            //from here start reaing user's feed with the help of access token
        }
    }
}
```

What i meant to do by it is that when the login button is clicked, the user is prompted his ***username*** and password.

However, the user is prompted to re-enter his password only, not to re-enter his username.

If I use the url without the `"&auth_type=reauthenticate"` parameter , it doesn't prompt for anything and straight sends me the access token.

How can I force the facebook to ask for a username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of fighting, the answer was under my nose.

You just need to call `https://www.facebook.com/logout.php` with your access token:

```
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Navigated += browser_NavigatedLogout;

        string logoutUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?" +
            "next=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" +
            "&access_token=" + MyAccessToken;


        try
        {
            browser.Navigate(new Uri(logoutUrl));
        }
        catch (System.Exception other)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error logging out: "+other.Message);
        }
```

and the handler is:

```
    private void browser_NavigatedLogout(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri == "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")
        {
           //here anything you need to do after the user logged off
        }
    }
```